# Parsing facebook oauth access_token string

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, facebook, oauth

Facebook returns access tokens in the form of a string:

```
'access_token=159565124071460|2.D98PLonBwOyYWlLMhMyNqA__.3600.1286373600-517705339|bFRH8d2SAeV-PpPUhbRkahcERfw&expires=4375'
```

Is there a way to parse the access_token without using regex? I'm afraid using regex would be unaccurate since I don't know what FB uses as access tokens

I'm getting the result like this:

```
result=urlfetch.fetch(url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",payload=payload,method=urlfetch.POST)
result2=result.content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook `access_token` and `expires` are returned as `key=value` pairs. One way to parse them is to use the [`parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) function from the [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) module.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> s = 'access_token=159565124071460|2.D98PLonBwOyYWlLMhMyNqA__.3600.1286373600-517705339|bFRH8d2SAeV-PpPUhbRkahcERfw&expires=4375'
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(s)
{'access_token': ['159565124071460|2.D98PLonBwOyYWlLMhMyNqA__.3600.1286373600-517705339|bFRH8d2SAeV-PpPUhbRkahcERfw'], 'expires': ['4375']}
>>>
```

There is also [`parse_qsl`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) should you wish to get the values as a list of tuples.

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qsl(s)
[('access_token', '159565124071460|2.D98PLonBwOyYWlLMhMyNqA__.3600.1286373600-517705339|bFRH8d2SAeV-PpPUhbRkahcERfw'), ('expires', '4375')]
>>> dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(s)).get('access_token')
'159565124071460|2.D98PLonBwOyYWlLMhMyNqA__.3600.1286373600-517705339|bFRH8d2SAeV-PpPUhbRkahcERfw'
>>>
```

Comment: Great! Although on appengine that I'm using, i had to import it from cgi